# Interpolate string from database

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

For example:

```
t = Test.new
t.test_string = "\#{foo} and \#{bar}"
t.save
```

And then I want to interpolate this string in one of my method.

I am already tried several options:

1. `ERB.new`

   `foo = 'Hello'
   bar = 'World'
   ERB.new(t.test_string).result`

It does not work, test_string print as `"\#{foo} and \#{bar}"`.

It work only if I print it without escape symbol '\'.

```
    ERB.new("#{foo} and #{bar}").result
 => "Hello and World"
```

But how can I make it programatic?

2. `eval`

   `foo = 'Hello'
   bar = 'World'
   eval '"' + t.test_string + '"'`

It works but it is not safe.

Do I have any other options? Or how to make `ERB.new` work?

Comment: "how to make ERB.new work" - use proper ERB syntax (`<%= %>`)

Comment: If you think you're automatically safe because you're using ERB, then know that `ERB#result` is implemented with `eval`. 

Comment: no one is safe =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't quite understand your needs.
Is it what you are looking for?

```
require 'erb'

erb_template = ERB.new('foo equals <%= bar %> and 2 + 2 = <%= 2 + 2 %>')
bar = 'baz'
erb_template.result(binding) # => foo equals baz and 2 + 2 = 4
```

`binding` method captures your current scope so ERB is rendering template in this scope.